# Any set $S$ contains a linearly independent set $T$ such that $span(S) = span(T)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is : Given any set $S$ of a vector space $V$ over a field $F$, prove that $S$ contains a linearly independent set $T \subseteq S$ such that $\text{Span}(T) = \text{Span}(S)$.

If $|S|$ is finite, we can use linear dependence lemma and keep popping out one element by one without changing the span such that we end up with a linearly independent subset. But I am stuck in the $|S|$ is infinite case. My thought was to say that since $\text{Span}(S)$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ containing all elements of $S$, then consider a basis $B$ of $\text{Span}(S)$. Then $B$ is linearly independent and $\text{Span}(S) = \text{Span}(B)$, hence I am done. Is this correct?

Comment: Why would $B$ be a subset of $S$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Oh good catch. Can you give me a hint for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal S=\{T\subset S\mid T\text{ is linearly independent}\}$. I shall use Zorn's lemma in order to prove that some element of $\mathcal S$ spans $\operatorname{span}(S)$.

If $\{T_\lambda\mid\lambda\in\Lambda\}$ is linearly ordered by inclusion (that is, if $\lambda,\mu\in\Lambda$, then $U_\lambda\subset U_\mu$ or $U_\mu\subset U_\lambda$), let $T_\Lambda=\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}T_\lambda$. Then $T_\Lambda\in\mathcal S$, since if $v_1,\ldots,v_n\in T_\Lambda$ and $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ are scalars such that $a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\cdots+a_nv_n=0$ then, since $\{T_\lambda\mid\lambda\in\Lambda\}$ linearly ordered by inclusion, there is some $\lambda\in\Lambda$ such that $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\in T_\lambda$ and therefore, since $T_\lambda$ is linearly independent, $a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_n=0$.

It follows then from Zorn's lemma that $\mathcal S$ has an element $T$ which is maximal with respect to inclusion. Suppose that $\operatorname{span}(T)\varsubsetneq\operatorname{span}(S)$. Then there is some $v\in\operatorname{span}(S)$ which cannot be written as a linear combination of elements of $T$ and therefore there is some $s\in S$ which cannot be written as a linear combination of elements of $T$. But then $T\cup\{s\}$ is a linearly independent subset of $S$ which strictly contains $T$, which is impossible, since $T$ is maximal with respect to inclusion.

Since $T$ is linearly independent and it spans $\operatorname{span}(S)$, it is a basis of $\operatorname{span}(S)$.